# execute terminal command within jsp application

Tags: java, jsp, terminal

I am developing a web application in jsp. At some point I have to execute the following terminal command within the application (code behind, of course).

```
java -jar rdfslice_1.42.jar -source test.nt -patterns "{?s ?p ?o}" -out output.out -order "S"
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Emrah

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It simply works as

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(COMMAND);
```

ProcessBuilder also works.